# An inequality about suprema and contraction function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $T\subset \mathbb R^2$ be a bounded subset and $\phi:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a contraction (namely $|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|\le |x-y|$ for all $x,y$). I want to prove ($t=(t_1,t_2)$ below)

$$\sup_{t\in T}(t_1+\phi(t_2))+\sup_{t\in T}(t_1-\phi(t_2))\le
\sup_{t\in T}(t_1+t_2)+\sup_{t\in T}(t_1-t_2)$$

Basically one need to show for all $(t_1,t_2)$ and $(t_1',t_2')$, one has

$$t_1+\phi(t_2)+t_1'-\phi(t_2')\le RHS.$$

I got stuck from here. If $t_2>t_2'$ and $\phi(t_2)>\phi(t_2')$ then we are good since $t_1+\phi(t_2)+t_1'-\phi(t_2')\le t_1+t_2+t_1'-t_2'.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$t_1+\phi(t_2)+t_1'-\phi(t_2') \leq t_1+t_1'+|t_2-t_2'|.$$ Suppose $t_2 \geq t_2'$. Then $t_1+\phi(t_2)+t_1'-\phi(t_2') \leq (t_1+t_2)+(t_1'-t_2') \leq $ RHS.  If $t_2 < t_2'$ then $t_1+\phi(t_2)+t_1'-\phi(t_2') \leq (t_1-t_2)+(t_1'+t_2') \leq $ RHS.

Comment: This seems to be wrong.  $(t_1,t_2)$ is supposed to be a point in $T \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with $t_1,t_2$ being two coordinates. But the answer confuses this with $t_1 \in T, t_2 \in T$.

Comment: @DanielLi I don't see any error in my proof except that I wrote $t_1,t_2 \in T$ instead of $(t_1,t_2) \in T$. I have edited my answer.

Comment: You said $t_1+t_1'\le \sup\{t_1+t_2:(t_1,t_2) \in T\}$. But this might not true since LHS $(t_1,t_1')$ may not be in $T$--$t_1'$ is the first coordinate here, $T$ is not the form $R \times R$.

Comment: @DanielLi Thank you for your comments. There was a  mistake in my argument and I have corrected it.