# A contraction inequality

Tags: inequality, lipschitz-functions

Show that $\sup_{t \in T}(t_1+\phi(t_2))+\sup_{t\in T} (t_1-\phi(t_2))\le\sup_{t \in T}(t_1+t_2)+\sup_{t\in T} (t_1-t_2)$ where $\phi$ is a contraction (Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant less than 1) and $T \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ is bounded.

There was a solution posted here [An inequality about suprema and contraction function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3544566/an-inequality-about-suprema-and-contraction-function). But I think the soution is false there. I have thought about this exercise long and hard. It seems that I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What do you think is false with the other answer? Why don't you leave a comment and ask for clarification?

Comment: @MartinR Put it simply, $(t_1,t_2)$ is supposed to be a point in $T \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with $t_1,t_2$ being two coordinates. But the answer confuses this with $t_1 \in T, t_2 \in T$.

Comment: So it is equivalent to conveniently assuming $T$ is of the form $R\times R$ which is not the original assumption.